# What is the quickest way of inserting/updating std::unordered_map elements without using an if?

Tags: c++, performance, unordered-map

I currently have lots of code which looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> my_dict;
.
.
.
// If the key does exist in the dictionary
if(my_dict.count(key) == 1){
    my_dict[key] = value;
}

// If its a new key
else{
    my_dict.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));
}
```

Is there any way I can speed this up by just overwriting the value every time?

Comment: Looks like you should use map

Comment: @billz I want O(1) insertion time? I don't want a tree O log(N)

Comment: the [] does this. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/ Of course, the complexity must be linear. If you want less insertion time, use a map

Comment: `my_dict[key] = value;` is all you need, no if required.

Comment: @janoliver: linear is only the worst case. if you are only interested in amortized cost, switching to map is a really bad idea.

Comment: @janoliver The odds of it being linear is an extremely derivative case.  It most/all cases it will be O(1) or very close.

Comment: You are right, I just realized that unordered map also uses some bucket like storage mechanism.

Comment: @All have added an edit

Comment: @user997112 Use `(*my_dict_ptr)[key]` or `my_dict_ptr->operator[](key)` then.

Comment: If you want to update the value each time, then just go for my_dict[key] = value.
However, if you don't want to update the value for an existing key, then your code is correct (and fastest).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You just do (for `map` and `unordered_map`)

```
mydict[key]=value;
```

Comment: using `if-else` would be faster if and only if default construction of `value` is very expensive. Though, in most of the cases `operator[]` does the job.

Answer (score 29):

I think it might be fastest like this:

```
auto it = my_dict.find(key);
if( it != my_dict.end() ) {
    it->second = value;
}
else {
    my_dict.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
}
```

that way you don't modify the structure of the `unordered_map` if the `key` already exists and you only have one lookup.

---

Note that the above, seemingly verbose code is more flexible than:

```
my_dict[key] = value;
```

This is because `Value& std::unordered_map::operator [] (const Key& key);` requires `Value` to have **default constructor** (in case of `value` not inserted by `key` - construct it first, than assign/replace) that maybe not present.

---

Another option in case you don't need/access `value` afterwards:

```
my_dict[key] = std::move(value);
```

This might be better in cases when the assignment of `value` is expensive and benefits from move-semantics.

Comment: @us2012 Mostly, but in the insert-case, it first inserts a default constructed value, then assigns it. The above avoids that overhead.

Comment: I'd do some serious measurement of the simple case (`foo[key]=value;`) before I go this route.

Comment: @Joe Yes. Without a profile run that shows that this is a problem, go for the more readable code. That *would* have been my answer when this question would lack the "performance" tag :)

Comment: My general experience is most people misinterpret which things are drags on their performance.  I'd expect the performance difference between the OP's code and either solution here to be very small in an `unordered_map`...

Comment: @DanielFrey: The `value_type` is `pair<const int, int>`. Any overhead will most likely be optimised away.

Comment: @MarceloCantos For this example, yes. I was thinking about the generic case.

Comment: If key is not present, this performs a search twice. You should just call `insert` and check the boolean return value.

Answer (score 11):

To update for C++17, you can use:

```
std::unordered_map::insert_or_assign()
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign

Comment: insert_or_assign() can be slower when using gcc.  see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95079

Answer (score 2):

All of your map functions perform a search, so you always search the map twice regardless of the key being present or not. You can leverage the fact that `insert` retrieves whether the insertion took place (key did not exist) or not (key exists) and act accordingly:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> mydict;
bool inserted = false;
auto position = mydict.end();
std::tie(position, inserted) = mydict.insert({key, value});
if (inserted) {
  pos->second = value;
}
```

This would be equivalent to `mydict[key] = value`, because we are assigning the new value no matter what. For types where default construction is cheap I would go with `operator[]` instead, if that's the only thing you need to do with the map.

All `insert`, `emplace` and `operator[]` can perform an additional construction of `value_type` in different situations: `insert` and `emplace` do this before the insertion takes place and `operator[]` default constructs the mapped value when key is not present. Thus, they are not ideal for types whose construction/copy/move is expensive (`std::thread`, very large `std::array`...). In this case, it is more appropriate to use `try_emplace` instead (C++17):

```
std::unordered_map<int, expensive_type> mydict;
bool inserted = false;
auto position = mydict.end();
std::tie(position, inserted) = mydict.try_emplace(key, expensive_constructor_args);
if (!inserted) {
  // no expensive_type has been constructed
  // pos->second references the existing value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you avoid extra typing by means of defining a function that saves you from typing the same again.
If you don't have access to C++17's `insert_or_assign()`, you can implement something like this yourself:

```
bool InsertOrAssign(std::unordered_map& m, int key, int value) {
  // Your code or one of the suggested answers goes here
}
```